# Unit tests no longer detected on project VS2017

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I am currently working on a C# WPF application and using MSTest to handle our unit tests. The unit tests are created in a separate project that is attached to the main project. until today all tests have been running with no issue. I performed a commit push on the previous working day, however when I opened the project today, when I run the tests, there are no results appearing. I had a colleague open the push I performed the previous day, and they are able to detect the tests and their results so I assume there is an issue in my config somewhere, I just don't know where to look.

EDIT:

we have uninstalled MSTest.TestFramework and MSTest.TestAdapter 1.1.18 and updated to 1.4.0 and the tests are being detected again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the source of the problem is... but I too have seen this behavior sometimes.  Try: (1) `Build => Clean Solution`, (2) Close & re-open VS2017, (3) `Test => Run => Run All Tests`